# How do I change a flatbutton.icon to a textbutton in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flatbutton

I have made a flatbutton icon, but it seems this is depreciated in the current flutter version. I have tried to upgrade it to a text button, but it does not show the text next to the icon.

This is the original code that has to be adapted to become a text button. Should I have to define a class or function to make it so?

```
Row(
            children: [
              FlatButton.icon(
                onPressed: () => print('Live'),
                icon: const Icon(
                  icons.videocam,
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
                label: Text('Live'),
              ),
            ],
          )
```

Thx! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an [`IconButton` widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/IconButton-class.html):

```dart
Row(
  children: [
    IconButton(
      onPressed: () => print('Live'),
      icon: const Icon(icons.videocam, color: Colors.red),
    ),
    Text('Live'),
  ]
)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `TextButton.icon()` widget. here an example:

```
TextButton.icon(
  onPressed: () => print('Live'),
  icon: Icon(Icons.videocam_rounded),
  label: Text('Live'),
),
```

and here the result:
[image: result]